# Summation of normal distribution in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I need to create a graph of this (trying to write it generically, I was using Python):

```
f(x) = sum([x*a>1 for a in gaussian(...)]) % some normal distribution
```

What I tried to use is this:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gaussian}{2}{\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gsum}{2}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\ret{0}%
\foreach \i in {#1}{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ret{\ret+(\i*#2>1?1:0)}%
  \xdef\ret{\ret}%
}%
\pgfmathparse{\ret}%
}

...

\addplot [
domain=0:1.5, 
samples=100, 
color=red,
]
{gsum(gaussian(0.75,0.25), x)};
```

What I was hoping to get (from Python):

[image: Python graph]

What I got was:

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated, I've looked for hours and can't find a solution, probably because I only started using this a few days ago.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you define a function with only two possible values at `\pgfmathsetmacro\ret{\ret+(\i*#2>1?1:0)}%` (if > 1: 1, if not > 1: 0).

Comment: The problem is that the variable \ret is not accumulating as I want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, I don't know exactly what function you want, so I plotted a few.

Your problem is, that you use `\pgfmathsetmacro\ret{0}` in the function. This resets `\ret` with each call, so nothing is summed up. Moving the initialization right before `\addplot` solves your problem.

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gaussian}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gsum}{2}{%
    %\pgfmathsetmacro\ret{0}% bad here, because it resets \ret every time
    \foreach \i in {#1}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\ret{\ret+(\i*#2>1?1:0)}%
        \xdef\ret{\ret}%
    }%
    \pgfmathparse{\ret}%
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gsuma}{2}{%
    \foreach \i in {#1}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\ret{\ret+(\i*#2)}%
        \xdef\ret{\ret}%
    }%
    \pgfmathparse{\ret}%
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gsumb}{2}{%
    \foreach \i in {#1}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\ret{\ret+(\i)}%
        \xdef\ret{\ret}%
    }%
    \pgfmathparse{\ret}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$f(x)$]
% initialise \ret
\pgfmathsetmacro\ret{0}%
\addplot [
domain=0:1.5, 
samples=100, 
color=red,
]
{gsum(gaussian(0.75,0.25), x)};

% initialise \ret again
\pgfmathsetmacro\ret{0}%
\addplot [
domain=0:1.5, 
samples=100, 
color=cyan,
]
{gsuma(gaussian(0.75,0.25), x)};

% and initialise \ret yet again
\pgfmathsetmacro\ret{0}%
\addplot [
domain=0:1.5, 
samples=100, 
color=green,
]
{gsumb(gaussian(0.75,0.25), x)};

% just to see the gaussian function
\addplot [
domain=0:1.5, 
samples=100, 
color=blue,
]
{10*gaussian(0.75,0.25)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]