# how can one plot an expression on pgfplots, which rounds a real number R to the nearest integer Z and computes a given series up to Z?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, function

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
xmin = 0, xmax = 1,
xtick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1},
xlabel={$\lambda$},
xmajorgrids,
ymin = 0, ymax = 100,
ytick={20,40,50,80,100},
ylabel={$\Sigma$},      
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white}]
 
\addplot [forget plot, color=black,solid,line width=0.5pt] {10*x + 1}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Series up to a rounded integer\label{fig:X}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Now, what I would like to do is to plot a function that, for each x value, calculates the real value R = 10*x + 1, then rounds R to the nearest integer value Z, and finally computes the series, S = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + Z. As you can see, R can easily be calculated. The problem I am having is to round R and compute S. Is there a synthetic way of doing this on LaTeX/ pgfplots? I can of course do these calculations pretty straightforwardly on Matlab (or Python, whatever), then store the resulting set of x and S values in a file, and plot the values contained in that file on LaTeX/ pgfplots, but I would prefer to have a more direct solution.

Comment: Are you looking for `pgfmath` functions? There's a whole bunch of them. `round` is certainly among them.

Comment: **@cfr**: thanks for the help. I had just found about about `pgfmathparse` for instance here [link](https://tikz.dev/math-parsin). However, I am not sure yet whether that also contains a series sum function or not. Also, not sure which packages to use and what exact syntax I should use. Any help on the basics, like a link or so, would be very welcome.

Comment: `texdoc pgf` VIII:94 'Mathematical Expressions'. There are also some additional functions provided by third-party packages/libraries, which would be documented elsewhere.

Comment: But note that you are almost certainly better off doing this externally. I think you'd probably have to write your own function for the series, but I'm not sure. Don't use this if you are interested in either speed or precision. There is also floating point available in `pgf` or (probably saner) `expl3`.

Comment: meanwhile, I found some probability density functions I had declared and plotted on .tex a while ago by using `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{function_name}{number_of_function_arguments}{\pgfmathparse{function_expression}}`. That should in principle get me there. If you could just tell me how I add inbuilt functions like `round` into this function declaration syntax I would be grateful.

Comment: I managed to declare the `round` function in the preamble and then plot it. Now, I only need to somehow nest it with a summation function declaration. I might find something here: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432852/summation-of-normal-distribution-in-pgfplots). In principle, I need to declare the summation function with a single parameter, the latter parameter being the result of the `round` function above. I'll try to implement that too. I will post my solution, if I manage to solve this last part

Comment: I've never done this. But you could look at the `tikz-ext` package which declares additional `pgfmath` functions to see how they are set up.

Comment: `S=Z(Z + 1)/2`, if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=100,
xtick distance=0.2, ytick distance=20,
xlabel={$\lambda$}, ylabel={$\Sigma$},      
xmajorgrids, ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
]
\addplot[red, domain=0:1, samples=100, thick] {10*x+1};
\addplot[green, domain=0:1, samples=100, const plot, thick] {round(10*x+1)};
\addplot[blue, domain=0:1, samples=100, const plot, thick] {0.5*round(10*x+1)^2+0.5*round(10*x+1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with linear and step functions]